# Testing arrays by value not type with chai

Tags: javascript, chai

Is there a chai way to compare arrays by value, not by type.

Example:

```
assert.deepEqual(new Float32Array([1,2,3]), [1,2,3]);
```

Of course I can write my own comparision or I can cast the second array info a `Float32Array` but I just want to know the values are the same and for the values above they are.

`sameMembers` also fails saying it expected an array.

I'd exepct some way to be able to compare to objects of different types just to check if their values are the same.

```js
const assert = chai.assert;

test(() => 
  assert.deepEqual([1,2,3], [1,2,3]));
test(() => 
  assert.deepEqual(new Float32Array([1,2,3]), [1,2,3]));
test(() => 
  assert.sameMembers(new Float32Array([1,2,3]), [1,2,3]));


function test(fn) {
  try {
    fn();
    console.log('pass:');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('fail:', e.stack.split('\n')[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.2.0/chai.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [deepInclude](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepinclude) instead and check the length of array first

```js
const assert = chai.assert;
const a = new Float32Array([1,3,2]);
const b = [1,2,3];

test(() => 
  assert.equal(a.length, b.length)
  &&
  assert.deepInclude(a, b));

function test(fn) {
  try {
    fn();
    console.log('pass:');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('fail:', e.stack.split('\n')[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.2.0/chai.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Comparing [1,2,3] to [1,3,2] will pass but needs to fail

Comment: You could iterate on the array, but i think deepEqual should work : you can open an issue [on github](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues)